# Undefined function 'int' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab

I am trying to get integral of L1 with respect to values of a and b, but it gives the following error:
Undefined function
'int' for input
arguments of type
'double'.

```
clear all, close all;  clc
format long
syms t a b;
a=0; b=12;

dt=0.7;
t=a:dt:b
ft=exp(-0.2*t).*sqrt(t)

Iexc=double(int(sym('exp(-0.2*t)*sqrt(t)'),a,b))

L1 = (((t-a).*(t-(2*a+b)/3).*(t-(2*b+a)/3))./((b-(2*a+b)/3).*(b-(2*b+a)/3).*(b-a)));
int(L1, a, b)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since integral in Matlab is used with `q = integral(fun,xmin,xmax)`, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html), not `int`: [States from CIC filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/int.html).